# How to fix 'PHP code not working in laravel public folder'

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, public, homestead

I embed a php in one of my views with:

```
<iframe src="{{URL::to('/')}}/game/game.blade.php" width="1519" height="690"></iframe>
```

In this file I have the following code:

```
<script>
    var userID = {{ auth()->user()->id }};
    var userCredit = {{ auth()->user()->id }};
</script>
```

I get the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

I already tried to use `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` etc.
I also tried to embed a link that used a route to another view but with this I got a 403 forbidden error.

Does anyone know how I could fix this? or have another solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

First, iframe src is never .blade.php file. You can create a route /game and map that route to controller which then returns the .blade.php view. So, in your view:

```
<iframe src="{{URL::to('/')}}/game" width="1519" height="690"></iframe>
```

And then in web.php

```
Route::get('game', 'HomeController@game');
```

And in HomeController.php:

```
public function game(){
    return view('game');
}
```

In which file are you writing  tag? What's the full error that you are getting? Maybe enclosing your variables inside quotes like this will solve the problem.

```
<script>
    var userID = "{{ auth()->user()->id }}";
    var userCredit = "{{ auth()->user()->id }}";
</script>
```

Comment: I have already tried to use "" around the auth user but it didn't work, maybe it is because it was inside the laravel public folder?

Comment: The view is inside public folder? Are you using this is .html files?

Comment: the view is in public folder and no I am not using .html files, I have found other solution tough for embedding it tough, thanks